# What's the advantage of using Capybara while I'm using Selenium 2 and Cucumber for functional testing?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara, functional-testing

I'm writing functional tests for a chrome app written entirely in javascript. I decided to use Cucumber and Selenium Webdriver and run the tests on chrome. Wrote Selenium code inside Cucumber step definitions and it works fine (I've only just begun though).

I see that I can do headless testing with capybara (or webrat) and I'm not interested in that. Is there anything else that I'd gain if I use capybara?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had the same question.  Capybara gives you a pretty nice DSL to interact with the DOM for one thing.  Another big advantage is you can easily switch drivers.  On my team, we constantly switch from the Chrome driver (desktop browser) to the iWedbDriver (mobile safari in iphone simulator).

Answer (score 0):

Headless testing is generally a very good thing, since the tests run faster if they don't have to draw the browser window. If the tests run faster, then you'll run them more often. If you're not interested in that, you're making a big mistake.

Comment: My selenium tests are basically "open browser, type in textbox A, click on button B, expect div C to have this text". I'm not testing my code itself but the behavior. How can I run headless tests of this kind if there's no dom?

Comment: How can you do that at all if there's no DOM? If something shows in the browser, there's a DOM, regardless of whether it came from an HTML document or was programmatically created by JavaScript. Or do I misunderstand? What's your UI like?

Comment: And headless tests can test the behavior. I run my Cucumber stories headless all the time.

Comment: @user968903 I know this is an old question, but I just reread your response and realized what you may be getting at. It sounds like you think that headless tests don't use a browser engine, which is not the case.  Headless Capybara tests (especially if you use something like capybara-webkit) actually *do* use a browser, with DOM and all that; they just don't make the DOM visible to humans. So you get all the advantages of a real browser test with better performance.